# Expand nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created nested gridview as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Staff" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand="Staff_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="Staff_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="Function" HeaderText=" Function" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="Team" HaeaderText=" Team" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="StaffCount" HeaderText="Staff Count" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FunctionID" HeaderText="FunctionID" Visible="true" />     
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="TeamID" HeaderText="TeamID" Visible="true" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CityID" HeaderText="CityID" Visible="true" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Show Details"/>
    <asp:TemplateField> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="StaffInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"> 
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"  />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="SOEID" HeaderText="SOEID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns>
```

```
protected void Staff_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        GridView StaffInfo = e.Row.FindControl("StaffInfo") as GridView;
        int functionid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
        int teamid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
        int cityid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
        StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityid, functionid, teamid);
        StaffInfo.DataBind();

        totalStaff += Convert.ToInt16(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "StaffCount"));
        Button showStaff = new Button();
        showStaff.ID = "this1";
        showStaff.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(showStaff);
        showStaff.Click += new EventHandler(showStaff_Click);

    }

    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total: ";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = totalStaff.ToString();
        Button showStaff = new Button();
        showStaff.ID = "this2";
        showStaff.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(showStaff);
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        showStaff.Click += new EventHandler(showStaff_Click);
    }
}
```

I would like to expand the nested gridview whe I click showStaff button.
I also want to pass the parameters to the stored procedure which launch after I click the button, but after I made the id fields not visible it doesn't work: I got error that the prarameters is not correct (when I set the fields visible there is no error).

EDIT:

I have added below event handler but i got error that GridViewCommandArgs doesn't contain a definition for Row:

```
    protected void Staff_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Checking for command name which command/button is pressed
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowDetails")
        {
            GridView StaffInfo = e.Row.FindControl("StaffInfo") as GridView;
            int functionid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            int teamid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
            int cityid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
            StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityid, functionid, teamid);
            StaffInfo.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have also changed the asp part:

```
<asp:ButtonField ItemStyle-Width="200px" ButtonType="button" DataTextField="StaffCount" CommandName="ShowDetails" HeaderText="Staff Count"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

EDIT2:

I write below event handler:

```
protected void Staff_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Checking for command name which command/button is pressed
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowDetails") 
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            GridViewRow row = Staff.Rows[index];
            GridView StaffInfo = (GridView)Staff.Rows[index].FindControl("StaffInfo");
            int cityID = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[5].Text.ToString());
            int TeamID = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[4].Text.ToString());

            StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, TeamID);
            Staff.DataBind();

            Response.Write(StaffInfo.Rows[0].ToString());

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But when I tries to disply Response.Write(StaffInfo.Rows[0].ToString()); I got error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

I checked the stored prodedure and it works fine. Any ideas what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot of stuff dynamically that I don't think you need to.

You already have the Show Details CommandRow.  If you handle the GridView's RowCommand event, you can capture the click for that button, and have access to which row the event occurred from.

Inside that click event, you can call your stored procedure, FindControl your nested GridView, and bind the sproc result to your nested GV.

I think this would be more straightforward.  Unless there's a specific reason you're doing the dynamic stuff.

Example:

In your CommandField, set the property `CommandText` = "ShowDetailsCommand".  Then, set up the event handler for Staff.RowCommand.

Inside Staff_OnRowCommand method, add a conditional:

```
if(e.CommandText=="ShowDetailsCommand")
{
    GridView StaffInfo = e.Row.FindControl("StaffInfo") as GridView;
    int functionid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
    int teamid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
    int cityid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
    StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityid, functionid, teamid);
    StaffInfo.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Edited with sample.  Not much different from what you already have.

Comment: Edited the first post. Garrison, I will appreciate if You will help me with this.

Comment: Sorry about that--found that the default e.CommandArgument will be the row index.  Check the example on this page to get the current row: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx

Comment: Excuse me Garrison but I still dont know how it should look like.

Comment: Thanks Garrison You helped me a lot but I still cant fill internal gridview. Please have a look on EDIT 2 in first post. Thanks.

Comment: Edit 2: it looks like you're databinding the parent, not the nested GridView.  Once you change it to StaffInfo.DataBind(), Rows[0] should no longer give you out of index error--unless there is no data returning from the sproc.

Comment: Yes it works now. I didn't noticed this. Will You be able to provide me sample link where can I move the child grid view "under" the parent record? Because now I see this as next column. Thank you in advance.

Comment: GridViews don't like pushing data into a new row.  If you want the child to display under in a new row, you'll need to switch to a Repeater.  The code should all transfer pretty nicely, but Repeater has less features than GridView out-of-the-box.

Comment: My point is to get the effect like below: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx Is this possible to avoid javascript and jquery?

Comment: So what I should use? Second: how can I get data from hidden columns? I want to hide id's columns. I tried t use GridView.DataKeys but I dont know how to assign parameters using DataKeys (there are 2 of them: cityid and teamid).